# Python - Glob without absolute path

Tags: python, path, glob

I m using glob in order to get names of pairs of pictures for a great number of images. The only problem is that i get absolute path and i dont want of that, i need only names of pictures. How can i do?

```
import glob

A=sorted(glob.glob('/media/test/A*.png'))
B=sorted(glob.glob('/media/test/B*.png'))
NumbSeq=len(A)
for i in range(0,NumbSeq):
  print "\"%s\",\"%s\","%(A[i],B[i])
```

I get that :

```
 "/media/test/A170900_85495.460376.png","/media/test/B170900_85495.460376.png"
```

I need that :

```
 "A170900_85495.460376.png","B170900_85495.460376.png"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
os.path.basename(A[i])
```

this will return the filename alone.

```
import glob
import os

A=sorted(glob.glob('/media/test/A*.png'))
B=sorted(glob.glob('/media/test/B*.png'))
NumbSeq=len(A)

for i in range(0,NumbSeq):
  print '"%s","%s"'%(os.path.basename(A[i]),os.path.basename(B[i]))
```

This will give you

```
"A170900_85495.460376.png","B170900_85495.460376.png"
```

Comment: thanks for your help! ;) but i get ' "A170900_85495.460376.png","B170900_85495.460376.png" ' and not "A170900_85495.460376.png","B170900_85495.460376.png" do you know how to suppress it?

Comment: @user3601754 Change the print statement to `print str(os.path.basename(A[i])) +"," + str(os.path.basename(B[i]))`.

Answer (score 19):

Instead of `glob(pathname)`, use the `glob1(dirname, pattern)` method to get the filenames.

```
>>> glob.glob1("some_dir", "*.png")
['foo.png', 'bar.png', ...]

>>> glob.glob("some_dir/*.png")
['/home/michael/A_dir/B_dir/some_dir/foo.png',
'/home/michael/A_dir/B_dir/some_dir/bar.png',
...]
```

Comment: I was surprised to learn that the glob module has undocumented functions. `glob0` and `glob1` non-recursively glob inside a literal directory. `glob0` only accepts a literal basename, but `glob1` accepts a pattern.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer glob1 over glob? Is it faster or something?

Comment: @Lou probably not much speed difference, but the difference is hopefully clear from my example. Using glob1 gives you files in a directory while glob gives you the entire absolute path. And those have different usecases.

Answer (score 1):

Pass each name in `A` and `B` to `os.path.basename` before printing them:

```
for i in range(0,NumbSeq):
    print '"%s","%s"'%(os.path.basename(A[i]),os.path.basename(B[i]))
```